# Linq query: inner join with a count() group by subquery

Tags: c#, sql, linq

We have some Machines having Devices attached. Not all the machines have devices atached and the devices cand be moved between machines. The devices generate Errors and we need to count those errors occured in the past day.

We have four tables: Machines (with Id and Code), Devices (with Id and Code), a pairing table DevicesMachines (Id, IdMachine, IdDevice, From datetime, To datetime) and Errors(Id, IdDevice, Moment datetime, Description).

The working SQL query is this:

```
Select m.Id, m.Code, 
   Coalesce(d.Code, 'NA') As DeviceCode,
   Coalesce(Err.ErrorCnt,0) As ErrorCnt
From Machines As m
Left Outer Join (Select IdMachine, IdDevice From DevicesMachines as dm 
Where GetDate() Between dm.From And dm.To) As dm on m.Id=dm.IdMachine
Left Outer Join Devices As d on dm.IdDevice=d.Id
Left outer join 
  ( Select IdMachine, Count(Id) As ErrorCnt From Errors as er 
    Where er.Moment >= DateAdd(day,-1,GetUtcDate()) 
    Group By IdMachine) As Err 
On m.Id=Err.IdMachine
```

I have tried many syntaxes, one of which is below:

```
using ( DataContextM dcMachines = new dataContextM())
{
  IEnumerable<MachineRow> lstM = 
    from m in dcMachines.Machines
    from dm in dcMachines.DevicesMachines.Where(dm => (dm.IdMachine == m.Id) && (dm.From <= DateTime.Now) && (dm.To >= DateTime.Now)).DefaultIfEmpty()
    from d in dcMachines.Devices.Where(d => d.Id == dm.IdDevice).DefaultIfEmpty()
    from er in dcMachines.Errors
        .Where(er => (er.Moment >= DateTime.Now) && (er.Moment <= DateTime.Now.AddDays(-1))) 
        .GroupBy(er => er.IdMachine)
        .Select(er => new { IdMachine = er.Key, ErrorCnt = er.Count() })
        .Where(er=> er.IdMachine==m.Id).DefaultIfEmpty()
 select new MachineRow
 {
    Id = amId,
    Code = m.Code,
    DeviceCode = (d == null) ? "NA" : d.DeviceCode,
    IdDevice = (d == null) ? 0: d.Id,
    ErrorCnt = (er == null) ? 0 : er.ErrorCnt
  };
}
```

I failed to find the right Linq syntax and I need your help.

Thank you,
Daniel

Comment: It would help to see the C# code of the classes so we can see navigation properties. And what is `DataContextM`, or, what flavor of LINQ is this?

Comment: Thank you @Gert Arnold, I tried to keep the example short and simple. DataContextM is a common DataContext containing the classes you asked for wich are simply mirroring the four tables I presented. The actual query has more han 20 tables but, as I said, I tried to simplify it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the SQL you provided, I created what I think is the equivalent EF LINQ expression:

```
using (var dcMachines = new DataContextM())
{
    var now = DateTime.Now;
    var utcYesterday = DateTime.UtcNow.AddDays(-1);

    var devicesMachinesQuery =
        from dm in dcMachines.DevicesMachines
        where dm.From <= now && dm.To >= now
        join d in dcMachines.Devices on dm.IdDevice equals d.Id into dItems
        from d in dItems.DefaultIfEmpty()
        select new
        {
            dm.IdMachine,
            dm.IdDevice,
            DeviceCode = d != null ? d.Code : "NA"
        };

    var errorsQuery =
        from err in dcMachines.Errors
        where err.Moment >= utcYesterday
        select err;

    IEnumerable<MachineRow> lstM =
        from m in dcMachines.Machines
        join dm in devicesMachinesQuery on m.Id equals dm.IdMachine into dmItems
        from dm in dmItems.DefaultIfEmpty()
        select new MachineRow
        {
            Id = m.Id,
            Code = m.Code,
            DeviceCode = dm != null ? dm.DeviceCode : "NA",
            IdDevice = dm != null ? dm.IdDevice : 0,
            ErrorCnt = (
                from err in errorsQuery
                where err.IdMachine == m.Id
                select err.Id
                )
                .Count()
        };
}
```

I made some tests in memory and it seems to yield the same behavior as your provided SQL query.

Comment: Thank ypu, @yv989c; it seems to work, indeed. Now I am in the process of extending the idea to the full query (with many more tables).

Comment: Btw, I have a question, though: such a "composite" query, containing other pre-defined queries (like devicesMachinesQuery or errorsQuery) is SQL optimised? The deferred evaluation ensures only one query is generated or there will be three (in this case) SQL queries?

Comment: I'm glad this helped you. Yes, EF will compose them into a single SQL query, you could observe this by using SQL Server Profiler. If you are new to LINQ using EF I strongly recommend using the tool LINQPad (https://www.linqpad.net/), with it you can execute LINQ expressions against your data source and observe the generated SQL and much more details of what's going on behind the hood.